# Download file and decoding its contents from FTP server to iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, download, ftp

I am new to use of ftp servers. Hence please be patient and if you have any suggestion please advice.

My problem is that I have to download files from FTP server to my ios application cache all in background thread and then decode it for its contents to display the data under several heads on the UI.

Now for this I understood that https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager provides me proper way of downloading file. Now my problem is that the file saved in server are in csv or xls format. **How do I read contents for it?** Is the data downloaded as a file in my ios app in a particular format which I then need to **parse for contents**. Basically, I don't have to display the file as is, but read its contents and then break them under several heads and display it on UI as various different parameters. Kindly throw any light on how to approach it. Any well written parsers for this case are welcome for learning purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, contents downloaded from a server are in `NSData` format. If you already know that the content will be a data that can be converted to string, you can use

`NSString *myCSVContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

to convert your downloaded contents to `NSString` and/or use

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

to parse the `CSV` contents easily.

**PS:** This is a `CSV` example, but you can do the same with `xls` contents the same way using a proper parser library.

https://github.com/QuetzalMX/QuetzalXLSReader

Comment: Great! Will look into it. Also, is this parsing done on background because I think initWithData method runs causes blockage on UI thread?

Comment: You can do it on a separated thread if you want, using gcd etc, but it would be an answer to another question. By the way, if this answer works for you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: yes Ninja I shall mark it accpeted as soon as I implement it in real time. Thanks a lot!